# Looping through the values of an array intersect

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have different communities in my database, such as: community_newsfeed, community_marketplace, community_games_requested, community_games_offered, events and custom_posts.
Each of those communities stores a post_id, as well as the user_id.
Then I have a community_users table that stores user_id and community_id.

I want to create a mechanism which I, as the authenticated user, can view all the posts of a user, as long as that user and I belong to the same community.
And on that regard, I must view only the posts for the communities which we both belong to.

So I do the following:

Get all the community id's of the communities which I(auth user) belong to:

```
$community_user_member = DB::table('community_users')->whereUserId($user->id)->pluck('community_id')->toArray();
```

Then I do the same for the user which I want to see the posts:

```
$requested_user = DB::table('community_users')->whereUserId($user_id)->pluck('community_id')->toArray();
```

Fine. Now I use array interect to give me all the community_id that we share only:

```
$members = array_intersect($community_user_member, $requested_user);
```

Now, this is where I get stuck.

How can I get the communities which the id match the values I get in the $members value(not the key) and the user id matches $user_id( this is passed in the url )?

```
if(!empty($members)){
    $newsfeed = CommunityNewsfeed::whereIn('newsfeed_community_id', $members)->whereUserId($user_id)->get();
}
```

I am sure that this user has 4 posts from community_newsfeed table, but I only see two posts, and also I dont see the correct posts.

Live example:

User A belongs to community_newsfeed.
User B belongs to community_newsfeed and community_marketplace.

User A must see the community_newsfeed data where user_id is the id of User B.

### Updated

Another option I tried was to use the in array function:

```
$common = [];
foreach ($community_user_member as $key => $member) {
    if (in_array($member, $requested_user)) {
        $common[] = $member;

    }
}
print_r($common);
```

The end result should be something like this:

```
$common = [ '4','5','10','20' ];
```

Because then I would be able to loop through $common array and do whatever I want.

But I get the following error when I refresh the page:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Comment: Try `array_values($members)` but I don't think that's the issue check if `$user_id` is correct or not

Comment: @Vineyif I get at array of key value pairs. Something like this:  
0: 229
1: 246
2: 248
3: 234

Now, Is there a way I can get an array of values only? Not sure if am confusing myself

Comment: Php array will always have a key bound with the values so there is not such thing as "array of values".So even when declaring array like `$a = array(1,2,3);` php internally creates it as `$a = array(0=>1,1=>2,2=>3);`, yes it's one of those quirky parts